# sharing session between Chrome plugin and web app keycloak

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, single-sign-on, keycloak

I am trying to create a web application and a chrome plugin. (chrome plugin is going to be a subset of my application). I am trying to give the SSO using Keycloak. The problem is, When i do the login in Webapplication and open the chrome plugin, chrome plugin again asks me to login.

I am using the following code in my plugin  (both web application and Chrome plugin written in Angular js)

ref article i used for doing SSO in Plugin : https://medium.com/tech-buddy/oauth-2-0-single-sign-on-authentication-in-chrome-extension-8f3f3ffd89c7

Question i have is, Both my plugin and web app uses the same clientid for authentication,

1. Is it possible to do SSO between web app and chrome plugin ?
2. If a user login to the Webapp and click the Chrome plugin it should not again ask the user to login for accessing the plugin ? meaning if a user login to any one of the application and opens a other one it should not ask for the login.

Comment: Which kind of keycloak adapter do you use to securize your application?

Comment: I am using keycloak-angular in my applications.